# Inheritance and derived classes in C# (DI case)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance, dependency-injection

So I'm following a tutorial about dependency injection with Unity in C#. In the tutorial, they used repository classes as an example to demonstrate the concept. Trying to apply that to one of sample projects, I encountered an inheritance problem. So I have

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> GetAll();

    T Get(int id);

    void Add(T entity);

    void SaveChanges();
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private CoffeeMachineDbContext context = null;

    protected virtual DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public Repository()
    {
        context = new CoffeeMachineDbContext();
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public Repository(CoffeeMachineDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The repository class implements the interface and the common methods.
Now To be able to apply dependency injection as it was explained (or at least as I understood it), I created a new interface named IClientRepository that inherits from IRepository as follow:

```
public interface IClientRepository : IRepository<Client>
{
    Order GetLastOrder(int id);
}
```

Notice that the interface declares a new method that it's specific to clients context.

Finally, the implementation of the IClientRepository interface is:

```
public class ClientRepository : Repository<Client>, IClientRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the client's last order
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Order GetLastOrder(int id)
    {
        Order lastOrder = null;
        Client client = DbSet.Find(id);
        if (client != null)
        {
            lastOrder = client.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return lastOrder;
    }
```

I don't need to implement the IRepository methods because they are common between all others.

The issue that I'm facing is that when I'm trying to register type in the unity container as follow:

```
container.RegisterType<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

I get the following error

The type 'CoffeeMachine.Models.Repositories.ClientRepository' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(IUnityContainer, LifetimeManager, params InjectionMember[])'. **There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CoffeeMachine.Models.Repositories.ClientRepository' to 'CoffeeMachine.Models.Repositories.IClientRepository'**.

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong here?

Comment: Why doesn't your ClientRepository implement IClientRepository?

Comment: Because when I do, I get the error: ClientRepository doesn't implement GetAll(), Get(int), etc..

Comment: It think you need the base class _and_ the interface: `public class ClientRepository : Repository<Client>, IClientRepository {...}`

Comment: I did that but it felt more like a hack than a solution. Do you have any explanation why would that be the case? Thanks

Comment: @SalimRahmani: Why does it feel like a hack to implement an interface?

Comment: @Slaks What I meant is that it feels like a hack implementing both Repository AND IClientRepository since IClientRepository is already inheriting from IRepository!

Comment: An IClientRepository is an IRepository. A Repository is an IRepository. A ClientRepository is a Repository. But a ClientRepository is not an IClientRepository according to your code. Just like a dog is an animal, and a cat is an animal, and a Labrador Retriever is a dog and an animal, but a Labrador Retriever is not a cat.

Comment: @mason Thank you! It makes perfect sense! I appreciate your help guys!!

Comment: Having entity-specific repository abstractions such as `IClientRepository` is a bad idea, as explained in [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error happens because your class doesn't actually implement `IClientRepository`.

You can only cast an instance to an interface if its class actually implements that interface.

Comment: That's what i thought in the beginning. However, once i do that I get the error: ClientRepository doesn't implement GetAll(), Get(int), etc...